# Database rows reading into list of objects

Tags: java, list, overriding

```
public static List<SPACE_CreateLicenseModel> SPACE_getDetails() throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, JSONException{

    SPACE_CreateLicenseModel view = new SPACE_CreateLicenseModel();
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection connect = null;
    List<SPACE_CreateLicenseModel> allData = new ArrayList<SPACE_CreateLicenseModel>();
    try {
        connect = SPACE_DBController.SPACE_getConnection();
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
        JSONObject obj = SPACE_Parse.parse ("C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM/WebContent/Data/SPACE_Database.json");
        String tablename = obj.getString("table_name");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename + " WHERE (SPLD_LicenseActiveStatus <> 5 OR SPLD_LicenseActiveStatus IS NULL)";
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        int i =0;
            while (result.next()) {     
                view.setSPLD_DeviceID_Mfg(result.getString(1));
                view.setSPLD_DeviceID_ModelNo(result.getString(2));
                view.setSPLD_DeviceID_SrNo(result.getString(3));
                view.setSPLD_DeviceID_Search_mode(result.getByte(4));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseType(result.getByte(5));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseTypeChangedDate(result.getDate(6));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseActiveStatus(result.getByte(7));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseActiveDate(result.getDate(8));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseAccess(result.getByte(9));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseAccessMaxNo(result.getInt(10));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseAccessCounter(result.getInt(11));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseStartDate(result.getDate(12));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseExpiryDate(result.getDate(13));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseeOrg(result.getString(14));
                view.setSPLD_LicenseeAddress(result.getString(15));
                view.setSPLD_LocationActive(result.getString(16));
                view.setSPDL_Longitude(result.getDouble(17));
                view.setSPDL_Latitude(result.getDouble(18));
                view.setSPDL_LocationTolerance(result.getFloat(19));
                view.setSPLD_FutureOption1(result.getString(20));
                view.setSPLD_FutureOption2(result.getString(21));
                view.setSPLD_FutureOption3(result.getString(22));
                view.setSPLD_FutureOption4(result.getInt(23));
                view.setSPLD_FutureOption5(result.getInt(24));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter1_FirstUseDate(result.getDate(25));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter2_MessageTotal(result.getInt(26));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter3_FailedAttempts(result.getInt(27));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter4_FirstFailedAttemptDate(result.getDate(28));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter5_LastFailedAttemptDate(result.getDate(29));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter6(result.getInt(30));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounter7(result.getInt(31));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounterOption1(result.getString(32));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounterOption2(result.getString(33));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounterOption3(result.getString(34));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounterOption4(result.getInt(35));
                view.setSPLD_StatCounterOption5(result.getInt(36));
                view.setSPLD_MainContact1Name(result.getString(37));
                view.setSPLD_MainContact2Name(result.getString(38));
                view.setSPLD_MobileNo1(result.getString(39));
                view.setSPLD_MobileNo2(result.getString(40));
                view.setSPLD_EmailID1(result.getString(41));
                view.setSPLD_EmailID2(result.getString(42));
                view.setSPLD_CustomerDetailOption1(result.getString(43));
                view.setSPLD_CustomerDetailOption2(result.getString(44));
                view.setSPLD_BroadCastGEN1(result.getString(45));
                view.setSPLD_BroadCastGEN2(result.getString(46));
                view.setSPLD_BroadCastID1(result.getInt(47));
                view.setSPLD_DevSpecGEN1(result.getString(48));
                view.setSPLD_DevSpecGEN2(result.getString(49));
                view.setSPLD_DevSpecGEN3(result.getString(50));
                view.setSPLD_DevSpecID1(result.getInt(51));
                view.setSPLD_DevSpecID2(result.getInt(52));
                view.setSPLD_MessageStatus(result.getString(53).charAt(0));
                allData.add(i,view);
                i++;
            }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(connect!=null)
                connect.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
    return allData;

}
```

I am fetching all the rows of the database and storing it in array. But while displaying only the last row is getting printed. The list elements are getting overridden. i.e., allData.add(1,view), allData.add(2,view) , allData.add(3,view) , allData.add(4,view) etc everything are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not creating a new Object for each iteration of the loop, it is re-using the same object, so try

```
Statement stmt = null;
Connection connect = null;
List<SPACE_CreateLicenseModel> allData = new ArrayList<SPACE_CreateLicenseModel>();
try {
    connect = SPACE_DBController.SPACE_getConnection();
    ....
        while (result.next()) {    
           SPACE_CreateLicenseModel view = new SPACE_CreateLicenseModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

Currently for each row same object is getting updated hence all your objects in list have same values (Last Row).

**Resolution:**

You need to initialize `SPACE_CreateLicenseModel`  each time in loop for every row.

```
while (result.next()) {     
       SPACE_CreateLicenseModel view = new SPACE_CreateLicenseModel();
       view.setSPLD_DeviceID_Mfg(result.getString(1));
.
.
       allData.add(i,view);
       i++;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view object with every iteration of your while loop. Every time you loop through the same view object is getting over written in memory. The final time your loop runs it replaces it with the last row values which is being displayed when you are printing your data...

```
while(yourCondition){
    view = new SPACE_CreateLicenseModel();
    //your code goes here....
}
```

Adding the above line in your loop will create a new view Object and will be added to your allData variable.